# One entity over three tables

Tags: java, jpa, mapping

Is it possible having one JPA entity over three or more tables? I know the @SecondaryTable annotation but the examples I had found showed only two tables. I have made a screenshot as an example:

[image: screenshot three tables]

Comment: yes this is totally possible. But what have you tried?

Comment: A secondary table will always use the PK of the owning table as its PK. This is fine for your second table, but not for your third one. That part has to be a relation to a different entity

Answer (score -1):

I think you can make it with jpa inheritance strategies. @Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.Yourstylehere)
That post may help you http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/
You should use table-per-class approach